# WebDriverIO - Select option from dropdown with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

**Here's the website, I'm trying to test:**
*https://opencart.abstracta.us/index.php?route=account/register*

*There are 2 drop-downs - Country and Region / State, they depend on one another.
Ex. Choose United States and in Region/State dropdown you will see US states and so on.*

**Example of my Code:**

```
  const countryDropdown = $(this.demoHomeElement.countryDropdown)
  countryDropdown.selectByAttribute('value', '223');
  //countryDropdown.selectByVisibleText('United States')
  browser.pause(3000);
  countryDropdown.selectByAttribute('value', '223');

  const zoneDropdown = $(this.demoHomeElement.zoneDropdown)
  //zoneDropdown.selectByAttribute('value', '3630');
  zoneDropdown.selectByVisibleText('Florida')
  browser.pause(3000)
```

The problem is when I execute the script - it selects the correct option, but the content in the next dropdown not getting updated (Displays the default stuff, instead of stuff for my selection).

Could somebody please help me with that?

Example:

Country dropdown - select "United States"
Region/State dropdown - displays states for UK.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: After you selected the dropdown of country, you need to wait for the website to load the zone. So you can try pause(3000) after selected the country.

Comment: Does the browser.pause helped?

Comment: Nope, the browser pause is not working.

Comment: I think it should works through “execute” command, should write a script that will change the selected to option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look how I did it and it works nicely in Chrome, did not check in other browsers:

```
describe("Test scenario", () => {
  it("Select drop downs", () => {
    browser.url(
      "https://opencart.abstracta.us/index.php?route=account/register"
    );

    $("//h1[text()='Register Account']").waitForDisplayed(); // just check that page elements are loaded on the page

    const selectBoxOne = $("#input-country");
    const selectBoxTwo = $("#input-zone");
    const spinner = $(
      "//i[contains(@class,'fa') and contains(@class,'fa-circle-o-notch') and contains(@class,'fa-spin')]"
    ); // after selecting BoxOne there will be a spinner...

    selectBoxOne.selectByAttribute("value", "103"); // Ireland

    browser.waitUntil(() => spinner.isDisplayed() == false); // wait for spinner to go away

    selectBoxTwo.selectByVisibleText("Dublin");
    browser.pause(5000); // Just to get a chance to see it
  });
});
```

Note: no matter what you select in the first drop down the selected value in the DOM element will remain unchanged to `United Kingdom`.

[image]

I hope this helps.

Wrote also an article for folks getting started with WebdriverIO [here](https://medium.com/me/stats/post/906c2729111e).

Comment: Well, yeah, it’s working the same way for me. Is there any way to change the selected option?
I mean, is there any way to force to use US and display states for US, instead of UK all the time?

Comment: Great, then can you please accept the answer if it is working. Regarding the selected option I see that there is the same behaviour if you do it manually so I'd suspect you will need to change the application code.

Comment: If you want to force during test execution that a specific <option> with get the attribute `selected = "selected"` you can do it via Javascript injection. Here is a simple example, you might need to adjust based on your needs, it selects Ireland (value = 103), it also removes the `selected = "selected"`  from UK.                         
 `browser.execute((value) => {
      document.querySelector("option[value='222']").removeAttribute("selected");
      document
        .querySelector("option[value='" + value + "']")
        .setAttribute("selected", "selected");
    }, "103");`

Comment: Check the `browser.execute` syntax if you need more flexibility: https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/execute.html

Comment: Please dont hesitate to accept the answer as it is working for you, right?